# Synonym of "to generate interest"

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the 1 word to describe "to generate interest"?

For example, David is generating customer's interest in his selling product.

Considering "tout" may not be a good choice. What is the 1 word (also a common word)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ***[Attract:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/attract)***

> (of people, things, places, etc.) to pull or draw someone or something towards them, by the qualities they have, especially good ones.

(Cambridge Dictionary )

> - *David is attracting  customers for his selling product.*

Comment: Not quite as straightforward as might be thought. What is attracted is not necessarily generated. The customers may be attracted, but their interest has to exist or has to be generated. I have proposed another answer.

Comment: @Anton - please see the definition, you attract someone showing the good qualities of something, thus generating interest in it. Interest in something is not a prerequisite. Think about a commercial which attract your attention and generates your  interest in a product you didn’t care much about before.

Answer (score 6):

To **Hype**:

Bill is hyping Andrew's portfolio.

Comment: This would be improved with a dictionary definition & link for your chosen word.

Comment: @Hugh Rection. thank you, I am just not sure if it's a common word. :)

Comment: @MarkK: It's extremely common in the context of new products, stock IPOs, etc. You can hype anything, no matter how old it is, but hype carries an implication that most people don't actually know about the product, so you're trying to create buzz from scratch, on little evidence/experience. For example, "hype" would be inappropriate to describe promoting Coca-Cola (the specific soda) itself, because people know what it is, generating excitement is hard, but you could hype a new *product* from Coca-Cola (the company).

Answer (score 5):

To **promote** (a product, service, etc.)

> 5. to encourage the sales, acceptance, etc., of (a product), especially through advertising or other publicity.
>
> [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/promote?s=t)

Answer (score 3):

If - as you specify in the question - the interest has to be generated, I suggest that he is stimulating or provoking interest.

> Stimulate =  encourage something to grow, develop, or become active
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stimulated)

Or provoking interest

> Provoke = to rouse to strong feeling or action
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/provoke)

If the interest already exists, he may be attracting it or nurturing it, but he cannot be said to be generating it.

Answer (score 2):

**Boost interest**

> **Boost:** to improve or increase something:
>
> - The theatre managed to boost its audiences by cutting ticket prices.
> - Share prices were boosted by reports of the president's recovery.
> - I tried to boost his ego (= make him feel more confident) by praising his cooking.

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boost)]

Answer (score 1):

**Pique**: To provoke; arouse (https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pique) is one possibility, as in *The statement piqued his interest*.

Comment: The sentence would still contain "interest".

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in our Help Center. We are not a link farm.

Comment: @tchrist: I only used hyperlink. BTW, I roll-backed the edit now.